# Limit in Characters in Function of Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using below code to display the `latest post` from `sub-domain` to `domain`--Here is the `code` i am using ---

I need to show the limit characters of `post_title` like to 30

Here is the code..

```
function render_my_recent_posts( $numberposts = 5 ) { ?>

    <ul>
    <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
            echo '<li><img src="/images/default-user-avatar-3.jpg"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
        }
    ?>
    </ul><?php
}
```

Any help ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `substr($recent["post_title"],0,30)` do what you need?

Comment: Yeah its beauty, i did not realize in ma own that i am can use `substr`. Thanks a lot, can we add name as well below title in `wp post` ?

Comment: Glad that helped, Kritika.  Not sure I followed your last question.  Do you mean can you add name of poster as well as title of post?

Comment: I think it should be.  Is the name of poster also in the $recent_posts array?  And where do you want the name of the poster to end up?